# BackTracking in C Sum of prime numbers?

Tags: c

I want to make a backtracking program to calculate the sum of every prime number smaller then n. Can you help me doing that ? I was working on a code but I do not know why it is not working ! Thx in advance !
I think I`m doing something wrong !

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int v[20],n;
void afisare(int k)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=k;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",v[i]);
    }
}
int valid(int k)
{
    int i,prim=0;
    for(i=1;i<k;i++)
    {
        if(v[k]%i==0)
        {
            prim++;
        }
    }
    if(prim==2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
void backtr(int k)
{
    int val;
    for(val=1;val<=n;val++)
    {
        v[k]=val;
        if(valid(k))
        {
            if(k<n-1)
            {
                afisare(k);
            }
            else
            {
                backtr(k+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("n=");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    backtr(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). More specifically, please learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line.

Comment: "I do not know why it is not working !" and we do not know how it is not working, please tell us. Describe how the program does not do what you want it to do. Compiler error? Crash? Hang? Wrong output? Wrong output for special intput?

Comment: I do however wonder why you ask user for input and then completely ignore it. I.e. why `backtr(1);` instead of `backtr(n);`

Comment: @Yunnosch The OP uses the ***global*** variable `n` in the `backtr` function. The problem is most likely the confusion the OP have about global and local variables, and what happens if there are two with the same name.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Good point. I did not notice that.

Comment: @Yunnosch To be honest, neither did I at first, until you mentioned it. :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and maybe read [ask].

Comment: Thx soo much for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I hope to help someone else

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int verify(int s) {
    if (s == 0) 
        return 0;
    else if (s == 1) 
        return 1;
    else 
        int z = 0;
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= s) {
            if (s % i == 0) 
                z++;
            i++;
        }
        if (z == 2) 
            return s;
        else 
            return 0;
}

int backback(int n, int s, int *sum) {
    if (s == n) {
        return;
    }
    int z = verify(s);
    *sum = *sum + z;
    backback(n, s + 1, sum);
    return *sum;
}

int back(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) 
        return 0;
    else if (n == 1) 
        return 1;
    else 
        int sum = 0;
        int x = backback(n, 0, &sum);
        return x;
}

int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("Insert an integer number: \t");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int x = back(n);

    if (x == 0) 
        printf("\nInvalid number");
    else if (x == 1) 
        printf("\nThe sum of prime numbers of the number %d is: \t%d", n, x);

    else 
        printf("\nThe sum of prime numbers of the number %d is: \t%d", n, x);

    return 0;
}
```